# implementation of periodic gaussian

Tags: python, c, matlab, numeric, numerical-methods

I am trying to implement periodic Gaussian in C, MATLAB or Python.

What is the correct way to evaluate the periodic Gaussian function as defined below

[image]

I am currently evaluating according to the formula below to avoid the summation over minus to plus infinity:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this question about a particular programming language or tool?

Comment: no it not particular to any language, I am asking how to programatically implement periodic Gaussian in any language, the difficulty is how to tackle the summation from minus infinity to plus infinity. Would be helpful to me, if you can provide an answer in either C, Matlab or Python.

Comment: @user3657953 It is better you ask your question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid the summation of infinity when using the modulus operator.  What is the resolution of `k`? Is `k` an integer? A real number? If it's a real number, then there isn't a way you can do it unless you use symbolic math, like Theano in Python or the Symbolic Math Toolbox in MATLAB.

Comment: yes, k is an integer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't have to evaluate the infinite sum, because once you get to (x-kL) >> 2sigma, you'll reach the limits of floating points precision.

So you should be able to start by finding the minimum of x - kL (i.e., just set x = x mod L and k=0, legit to do because this is an infinite sum) and then adding the terms at k = +/- 1, +/- 2, ... until you reach floating point limits.  Here's some example MATLAB code that illustrates the idea - I just whipped this up so I can't promise it's bug-free, but it does seem to exhibit some of the basic expected behavior.

```
    function [result] = Periodic_Gaussian(x, L, sigma)

    gaussian = @(y) 1/(2*pi*sigma)*exp(-y.^2 ./ 4 ./sigma^2);

    x = mod(x, L);

    oldresult = NaN;
    newresult = gaussian(x);
    k = 1;
    while any(newresult ~= oldresult)
        oldresult = newresult;
        newresult = oldresult + gaussian(x-k*L) + gaussian(x+k*L);
        k = k+1;
    end
    result = newresult;
```

Hope this is helpful!

EDIT: Missed a factor of 4 in the denominator of the argument to the exponential, and updated the code to take a vector of x if desired.

Comment: thanks, but this function returns the same result for any given L

Comment: I don't know what L values you tested, but it shouldn't, unless I made an error in copying it over: `Periodic_Gaussian(11, 2, 1) = 0.2821, Periodic_Gaussian(11, 8, 1) =0.0171`, for example.

Comment: I meant same result for fixed L and varying x and sigma, in your example you are keeping x constant (= 11) Btw, this is what I get for Periodic_Gaussian(11, 8, 1) = 1.9641e-05 and PeriodicGaussian(11, 2, 1) = 0.1171.... and for L = 1, I get PeriodicGaussian(11, 1, 5) = PeriodicGaussian(0, 1, 5) = 0.2821

Comment: Your second set of outputs makes sense to me - the Gaussian is periodic.  If L = 1, then the function should return the same value for 11 or 0, because 11 is 0 + an integer multiple of the period L.  `PeriodicGaussian(x1, L, sigma) == PeriodicGaussian(x2, L, sigma)` for any x2 = x1+k*L, this is the definition of periodicity.  Also a note, when sigma >> L, as in your example, this function will be approach a constant value for all x.  Though I did notice a mistake in the code above explaining the different values we get, I've edited it now to fix.

Comment: yes, you are right.. you have a small typo in the code, it 2 not 4 by definition. Finally I have a code which does the same thing without the while loop posted below. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
function [result] = PeriodicGaussian(x, L, sigma)                                                                                                                                                                                             



    gaussian = @(y, sigma) 1/(2*pi*sigma)*exp(-y.^2 ./ 2 ./sigma^2);                                                                                                                                                                           


    x0 = mod(x, L)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    x1 = mod(x, -1 * L)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    result = gaussian(x0, sigma) + gaussian(x1, sigma);                                                                                                                                                                                        
    correctionIdx = (x0 == 0 & x1 == 0);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    result(correctionIdx) = 0.5 * result(correctionIdx);                                                                                                                                                                                       

end
```